# Чтение данных из файла

Tags: c#

Скажите, у меня есть такой код

```
for (int i = 1; i < max_acco; i++)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(textusername.Text + ".acc", FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

            bw.Write(textusername.Text);
            bw.Write("\n");
            bw.Write(textpassword.Text);
            bw.Write("\n");
            bw.Write(textemail.Text);
            bw.Close();
        }
```

Так вот он записывает в файл логин и пароль, так вот, а потом я хочу прочитать эти данные, но я не знаю, как прочитать и передать в переменные такое

Вот содержание файла:

- testqord
- 159357
- blalbal@gmail.com

Так вот я хочу, чтобы первая строка перешла переменной x1, а вторая строка перешла переменной x2. Как это сделать в классе BinaryReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаете, по всей стандартной библиотеке и в том числе по классу [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) есть отличная документация. Всё что вам нужно — это посмотреть туда и воспользоваться методом [ReadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring.aspx).

```
BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(textusername.Text + ".acc", FileMode.Open));
String x1 = binReader.ReadString();
binReader.ReadString(); //пропускаем '\n'
String x2 = binReader.ReadString();
binReader.Close();
```

И вы уверены, в необходимости добавлять в файл переводы строк?

```
bw.Write("\n");
```

Ведь класс BinaryWriter сохраняет строки в файл не как текст, а именно как объекты, и поэтому в состоянии самостоятельно понять где кончается одна и начинается другая строка.

Comment: Спасибо, но если это имя пользователя я не знаю какова будет длина логина или пароль...

Comment: А зачем вам их знать?

Comment: Ну и как программа их будет знать, если они все будут в одну линию?

Comment: Ещё раз: класс BinaryWriter сохраняет строки в файл не как текст, а именно как объекты, и поэтому в состоянии самостоятельно понять где кончается одна и начинается другая строка.

Comment: Ааа понял, спасибо большое)